# Calculate coordinates of point in another plan

Tags: javascript, math, matrix, coordinates, points

I need to get x and y of a point in another plan. I'll explain:

```
- I have a plan where xmin = 0 & xmax = 720 & ymin = 0 & ymax = 894. 
- I have another plan with xmin = -3900 & xmax = 6000 & ymin = -4000 and ymax = 8000.
```

- For the first plan the origin (0;0) is on top left.
- On the second plan the origin is on the middle of the plan (in approximately 433;734 coordinates on the first plan). The top left point is -3900;8000.

What i need to do is to get coordinates of points, set in the second plan, in the first plan. For example if i search coordinates 0;0 of the second plan in the first plan i need to get 433;734 and if i search -3900;8000 i need to get 0;0 in the first plan.

I need to do this in JavaScript I hope you'll understand me well.

Thank you.

EDIT : Thanks you @MBo who work with me and find this solution. The first map is : http://rolux.org/svg/radar.svg and the second is : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-zvE86DVcv2MXhVSHZnc01QWm8/view

```
x_1 = (x_2 + 4000) * 1080 / 10000
y_1 = (8000 - y_2) * 1080 / 12000
```

Comment: How would you do this mathematically? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to get what i want with some equations but i do not find. You think it's impossible ?

Comment: No it is actually really simple. Edit your post to include your equations and we will try to help you if you are still stuck. But we won't do your homework since that wouldn't help you in the long run.

Comment: Excuse me it's not my homework, i'm a pro i'm just no familiar with that kind of concept.

Comment: I don't quite understand where your numbers are coming from (the `433/734`). Could you add an image that shows this?

Comment: The 2 plans are the same map, but the coordinates of the plans are very differents. Because it's the same map i could locate the 0;0 of the second plan in the first plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the simplest mapping is linear.

To transform coordinates from the first plan to the second one, you need to subtract first origin, multiply by scale coefficient and add the second origin.

```
x2 = (x1 - origin1.x) * xsize2 / xsize1 + origin2.x
```

For reverse transform use inverse coefficient:

```
x1 = (x2 - origin2.x) * xsize1 / xsize2 + origin1.x
```

The same for y-coordinates.

It is hard to say - whether this approach is applicable to your task because description is still rather tangled...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just need to transform from the second in the first (so the 2nd equation). What i don't understand in your equation (if i understand it well) it's that the origin2 (the origin of the second plan) is 0;0 in its own plan but it's 433;734 in the other plan. What i need to substract ? To be more specific if i search 433 (of the first plan) x1 should be 0 right ?

Comment: As far as I understand `origin1.x = 0, origin2.x = 433`. And I don't sure what `433 (of the first plan) x1` does mean.

Comment: Well that's not really what i meant my apologies. Both origins are of course 0;0 0;0. The 2 plans are the same map (map of a city) but xmax & ymax & position of the origin aren't the same. As i said the first map have its origin on top left and the second in the middle center. So i search approximatively the coordinates of the origin of the second map IN the first map and that's what i got.

Comment: Are scales similar for two maps?

Comment: Yes, the really problem is that the origin are completely different.

Comment: So you have "master coordinate system", and two maps origins (0,0) have some offsets in that system. Just add or subtract difference of these offsets. For example, one map has top corner at London with latitude 51. and another map - at Paris with latitude 49. Map has scale 100 pixels/degree.  Y-Coordinate of Marseille (lat 43) at the second map is 600 (-(43-49)*100), and at the first map is 600+2*100 = 800

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203577/discussion-between-philigane-and-mbo).